# Problems appending lines from a script

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

I'm writing a script and here's how i'm inputting into the `CurrentOutput.csv` file.

```
echo "$col1,$col2" >> CurrentOutput.csv
```

---

`Input.txt`

```
1.2.3.4
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
```

`CurrentOutput.csv`

```
1.2.3.4
,DNS1
2.3.4.5
,DNS2
3.4.5.6
,DNS3
```

`DesiredOutput.csv`

```
1.2.3.4,DNS1
2.3.4.5,DNS2
3.4.5.6,DNS3
```

---

I've tried `echo -e "$col1,$col2\c"` and `echo -n "$col1,$col2"`. Is it because I'm writing from a `.txt` file to a `.csv` file? What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you getting `col1` and `col2`?

Comment: a .csv file is a Text file but with a comma separated values, so it doesn't matter the what extension it is, what i see is that there is an EOL character in the end of the input value of 1.2.3.4 like if there is this in a C code 1.2.3.4\0 now what i think you should do is to remove that EOL character, try  this col1=$(echo $col1 | tr -d '\n') before calling the echo "$col1,$col2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found out the answer, there was carriage returns and an `^M` char which I had never seen. This question can be deleted.